# Will Windows 7 setup overwrite Windows 8 and Ubuntu boot records?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, windows-8, installation

I have Windows 8 and Ubuntu installed, both an the same physical hd (2 partitions). Windows 8 was installed after a format, Ubuntu afterwards. I used EasyBCD to setup the boot records and the boot menu order.

I want to install Windows 7 as a third operating system and just add its boot record with EasyBCD.

Will there be any unwanted behavior when I install it on a third partition? I already have 100 GB of unallocated space on the disk, though have not yet made the partition.

I red on [this site](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/90972eec-177a-4939-a159-e7294a5a8e52/windows-7-mbr-overwrote-windows-8-mbr-windows-7-only-shows-up-on-the-boot-manger?forum=w8itproinstall) that I should install the oldest OS first, but than I would have to do a format and start again from scratch (which I clearly do not want to do).

edit:
On [this site](http://www.pagestart.com/win8dbwin701181301.html), the opposite is claimed, saying it's also possible to install Windows 7 after Windows 8. However, it will restore a Windows 7 boot menu instead one of Windows 8.

Comment: adding a third os is no different then adding a second os to a disk

Comment: @Ramhound But wont the setup of Win7 overwrite all records?

Comment: Yes it will, you should install them in this order Windows 7, Windows 8, then Ubuntu, however because you have Ubuntu, you can install Windows 7, then use a live Ubuntu disc to reinstall Grub, after you reinstall Grub you should get an option to select either of the three. I don't remember exactly the process to reinstall Grub, but you should be able to find easy directions to follow on Google.

Comment: @TheX Will it make any difference if I ditch Ubuntu? Just installing Win7, but keeping the Win8.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because Ubuntu grub boot loader chain loads Windows 8 and Ubuntu boot loader. After installing Windows 7 GRUB will be removed meaning the inability to boot to Windows 8 and Ubuntu. So after installation run Live version of Ubuntu (burn the Ubuntu ISO to USB and then boot USB from BIOS). When Ubuntu setup opens chose 'Try Ubuntu'. Connect to Internet.

Open Terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

After boot repair is installed type 'boot-repair' in terminal (remove the quotation marks) or open boot repair by searching for it in Dash.

As boot repair window opens click on 'Recommended Repairs'. It will install GRUB boot loader and will chain load Windows 7 and Windows 8 boot loaders. Restart and now you have a TRI-BOOT computer!!!